# How to guide rear brake cable in a frame without brake guides?

Tags: brakes, cable-routing

I recently bought a fixed frame (polo and bike Williamsburg) which I want to ride as singlespeed.

The frame has the hole for the rear brake but does not have any attachment to guide the cable.

What should I buy in order to guide the cable on how should I install it?

Thank you!

Comment: Google `bicycle cable guides`.

Comment: A quick solution is to use a single long piece of housing from the lever to the brakes and zip tie it to the frame

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `top tube cable clamp`  probably 3 of them, maybe 4.  Two will be insufficient.

[image: https://www.recycleandbicycle.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/simp-3-small.jpg]

Do measure your top tube first - Top tube could be 25.4mm (1 inch) or 26mm, and you want it right diameter.

This shows how the clamps are installed along the top tube to retain the rear brake cable housing, which is one single long piece of outer.

[image: Raleigh Professional from Sheldon Brown's site https://www.sheldonbrown.com/retroraleighs/1970Pro-1-mid.jpg]

Comment: So just having the cable housing squeezed into the frame is enough?

Comment: @nck sorry not sure what you're asking there.   Have included a pic to show them installed.

Comment: You’ll need a continuous piece of cable housing.

Comment: @Michael you're right - "one single long piece of outer."

Comment: I'm not able to find a photo to illustrate it. But usually you have the cable housing going to the first attachment in the frame, then it goes without housing through the frame, and then there is another attachment in the frame and another piece o housing until the frame. With this system that you show me, are not the clamps smashing the cable and not allowing it slide correctly?

Comment: By the way, I can't find clamps around 4cm wich is the diameter of my toptube. Does this work the same way? https://static.bike-components.de/cache/p/xl1/1/7/BBB-HydroGuide-BCB-94-Cable-Guide-black-universal-17128-44448-1481265051.jpeg

Comment: @nck No sorry.  Those black plastic things are for hydraulic disk brake hose, so they're the wrong size, and they still need to be attached to the bike.   If your bike's top tube is 40mm in diameter then its bigger than bikes before the 90s, where those clamps would be used.  So you'll have to make your own, or just use some zip ties or electrical tape to do the same job.  The pictured clamps don't crush the cables at all. The system as described in comments is a more modern brazed-on cable stop, which stops the outer for a part of the run.  This is possible too, but needs brazing of stops.

Comment: @Criggie Thank you, it is a pitty to get such an expensive new single speed frame and put electrical tape or zip ties, but I'll see what can I find. Thank you!

Comment: @nck if its not too late - return the frame.   Buy what you need and avoid having to modify it.

Comment: @criggie Unfortunately is not an option as I bought it as a bike and change almost everything. I think i will have to step to those zip ties